# Multiple function calls with Promise.all

Tags: typescript, promise

I have multiple functions like the following

```
private async p1(): Promise<Result> {
    let p1;
    // Do stuff.

    return p1;
}

private async p5(): Promise<void> {
    // Call some external API.

}
```

Some of them have a `return`, some don't. But all of them do something very specific and they don't depend on each other.

I'm trying to call all of them asynchronous with Promise.all() and have them executed in parallel (with fast fail safe). I have up to 15 calls, like the following snippet:

```
    let [x1, x2, x3] = await Promise.all([
        this.p1,
        this.p2,
        this.p3,
        this.p4,
        this.p5,
        this.p6,
        this.p7,
        this.p8,
        ...
        this.p15
    ]);
```

However, I'm greeted with

```
src/app/view-models/index.ts:69:37 - error TS2345: Argument of type '(Promise<void> | Promise<Result>)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Iterable<void | PromiseLike<void>>'.
  Types of property '[Symbol.iterator]' are incompatible.
    Type '() => IterableIterator<Promise<void> | Promise<Result>>' is not assignable to type '() => Iterator<void | PromiseLike<void>>'.
      Type 'IterableIterator<Promise<void> | Promise<Result>>' is not assignable to type 'Iterator<void | PromiseLike<void>>'.
        Types of property 'next' are incompatible.
          Type '(value?: any) => IteratorResult<Promise<void> | Promise<Result>>' is not assignable to type '(value?: any) => IteratorResult<void | PromiseLike<void>>'.
            Type 'IteratorResult<Promise<void> | Promise<Result>>' is not assignable to type 'IteratorResult<void | PromiseLike<void>>'.
              Type 'Promise<void> | Promise<Result>' is not assignable to type 'void | PromiseLike<void>'.
                Type 'Promise<Result>' is not assignable to type 'void | PromiseLike<void>'.
                  Type 'Promise<Result>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<void>'.
                    Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
                      Type '<TResult1 = Result, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Result) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = void, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: void) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | null | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
                        Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
                          Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
                            Type 'Result' is not assignable to type 'void'.

 69         const x = await Promise.all([
                                        ~
 70             this.p1,
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
 81             this.p15
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 82         ]);
```

If I try to add just (up to) 11 calls, ANY of them, everything works as expected. As soon as I add the 12th function call the above error is triggered.

Is there something I'm missing or any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to reproduce this as soon as you hit 11 elements. The built-in header [lib.es2015.promise.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L41) includes overloads of up to 10 elements, but [as Bergi mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598045/1426891), as soon as you hit 11 it assumes that the list items are homogeneous.

In addition to nesting Promise.all, you can also use an explicit generic to type the return values as `unknown`. With this, you will be unable to do any meaningful operation to the elements of the list, but unless you are intending to pull specific Results out of the list that shouldn't matter much.

```
// bar is of type Promise<unknown[]>
let bar = Promise.all<unknown>([foo1(), foo2(), foo3(), foo4(), foo5(),
    foo6(), foo7(), foo8(), foo9(), foo10(), foo11(), foo12(), foo13(),
    foo14(), foo15()]);
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=47&pc=159#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL3egjACgEoAuGABQCd0BbVEAUwB4A3dVAEwD4YBvAWABQggL6DQkWIhQYscHACYipSjTpMQyCqggBzbvwEwYFesgQUsAcksBuEWPDR4SKGkzZ0AZiXkqtBixsXLyC9gLiTlKuMh4ALD4q-uqa2nohhsam5la2YRGSLm6yOACsCX5qgRz6oQKi4Y4F0u5y6ABs5aoBGlq6NRkmZhYw1nZ1DhLOzcXoAOydSVXBBnmNU9EtOAAcC5U9qf1Gg9kjueMNk1FFHgCcuwGs1emrl4UxrbgADPfJvWkGRyyw1GL0ib02eAIJF8XSYj2WtXq+XW1w+imhiT2KT66UBQxyYyRayu7xwuG8GIqDyC-VBTQ2M1w8UpsMY+xxAMy+NOhImYOmHlwZRZi3htPOggANqYYAAjYAUGAAXhhSQAdMBJZLGEgANYQdAAdwgnHwAG0PkQADQedE21oU+04ZlO9DC10dQiu+Zejw7X2tO4BsnfYOQ62Cu2Cx2Cl2C4UAXUIQA)

Comment: I defined myself a generic TODO type (as descirbed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/4p2r6e/type_todo_any_lazy_gradual_typing/) ) and it seems to work, as you said.
I am not sure if I should accept your answer or Bergi's answer as both of them are correct :)

Comment: @JakobAttk I'm glad we both gave you helpful options! I do recommend accepting at least one of our answers to indicate that you no longer have this problem—nominally ["the best solution to your problem"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), but that's entirely up to your judgment. Good luck with your project! :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems like tuple types (heterogenous arrays, where each element has its own type) are only supported for up to twelve elements. Or at least the overload declarations of `Promise.all` stop there, and Typescript infers that you must be passing a list (of arbitrary length, with only a single element type).

A rather simple workaround is to nest the `Promise.all` structure:

```
let [x1, x2, x3, _] = await Promise.all([
    this.p1,
    this.p2,
    this.p3,
    Promise.all([
        this.p4,
        this.p5,
        this.p6,
        this.p7,
        this.p8,
        ...
        this.p15
    ]),
]);
```

Comment: +1, but I would have expected the count to be 10, per [lib.es2015.promise.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.promise.d.ts#L41).